# Embedding Justin.tv player on https page

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, justin.tv

I've run into a slight issue whilst trying to embed the Justin.tv player into my page. The page is using a https connection and I want to keep it that way at all costs.

Justin.tv doesn't have an SSL certificate for the part of their website that you embed their player from.

If I put the regular embed code in, it doesn't load it for some reason. If I put it in an iframe then it loads it, but the player knows it's in an iframe and shows an error message stating it can't be used within an ifame. If I embed it when https in the protocol, it sometimes loads, and sometimes doesn't. All of the times none-the-less it doesn't let me keep my nice green https:// in the address bar either :(

Can anyone come up with some way of doing this? :D

Edit: Forgot to mention, I'm running Nginx and PHP 5.3.

Comment: have you asked the folks at Justin.tv why they don't support encryption? This is really their problem not yours. In the meantime LiveStream seems to support encryption; although their cert is only valid for subdomains (*.livestream.com)

Comment: Never-mind, LiveStream's encryption seems to only apply to new.livestream.com not regular streams at www.livestream.com; my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since they have stopped you from adding the player in this way...

Either you remove ssl on your page...

Or you can make your page pop up a new window just for the player.

---

BTW, the not letting you keep the green https in address bar:

It is **by design**, so that the user knows it is not entirely secure. This is because normally a user would expect the **whole page** to be secure. This lets them know that they should be careful entering their **very public** credit card info!

Comment: Yeh, I now it's just annoying after having paid for it... Thanks for your input. :)